# Why Is Matlab Ignoring My If Statements?

Tags: matlab

So I have to write program that solves for these rules:

Find a six digit number in which the first digit is one more than the third, the second digit is one less than the fourth, the fifth digit is one less than the third, and the sixth digit is one more than the fourth.  The sum of the second and third digits equals the first.  The sum of all digits is thirty.

I am only allowed to use nested `for` and `if` statements and this is what I came up with:

```
for I = inf
    for n4 = (1:9)
        n6 = n4 + 1;
        n2 = n4 -1;
        for n3 = (1:9)
            n1 = n3 + 1;
            n5 = n3 - 1;
            if (n1 - n2 == n3)
                if (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 == 30)
                    break
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The issue I am having is that Matlab ignores all my `if` statements because at the end of the program, `n1 - n2 = 0`, `n3 = 9`, and the sum `n1+n2+...+n6 = 22` not `30`. This is my first project in Matlab so I hope I gave enough information for this question,
Thank you!

Comment: A single call to `break` will only break out of the innermost for loop. You need to save those variables for safe keeping later. Otherwise the outer for loops keep going, overwriting your digits. Also, `for I=inf` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. When I run your code it works like a charm and I get an answer which says that n1=9, n2=1, n3=8, n4=2, n5=7 and n6=3.

Comment: @NickyMattsson if you run the code exactly as written it's impossible for you to get that result.

Comment: @excaza, I should, of course, have said that I added 6 printout statements, but the question was regarding the functionality of the code, not how to write out values.

Comment: Which I'm assuming are located at the `break` statement, which is only reached once and it's not at the termination of the program...

Comment: @excaza, Only one combination of n1-6 satisfies the if condition.

Comment: That's great, this program does not return that, which is the whole reason why he asked the question. Maybe try running the code as written...

Comment: I see the "real" problem now. I never understood that we literally ran the script without saving or writing out the values out at the right time. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works perfectly and give right result, the only problem:
as already told `break` interrupts only 1 inner for loop.

If this is the whole code of your program you can use `return` instead of `break`. 
Another way:
use some logical index.
For example:

```
flag = 0;

for I = inf
    for n4 = (1:9)
        n6 = n4 + 1;
        n2 = n4 -1;
        for n3 = (1:9)
            n1 = n3 + 1;
            n5 = n3 - 1;
            if (n1 - n2 == n3)
                if (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 == 30)
                    flag = 1;
                    break
                end
            end
        end
    if flag==1
        break
    end
    end
end
```

By the way. The answer is `918273`.